# Android + sqlite insert speed improvements?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, saxparser, sqliteopenhelper

I recently inherited a project where a sqlite db is stored on the users sdcard (tables and columns only, no content).  For the initial install (and subsequent data updates), an XML file is parsed via saxParser storing it's contents to the db columns like so:

**saxParser:**

```
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            currentElement = false;

            if (localName.equals("StoreID")) {
                buffer.toString().trim();
                storeDetails.setStoreId(buffer.toString());
            } else if (localName.equals("StoreName")) {
                buffer.toString().trim();
                storeDetails.setStoreName(buffer.toString());
            ...

            } else if (localName.equals("StoreDescription")) {
              buffer.toString().trim();
              storeDetails.setStoreDescription(buffer.toString());
              // when the final column is checked, call custom db helper method
              dBHelper.addtoStoreDetail(storeDetails);
            }

            buffer = new StringBuffer();
    }           


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (currentElement) {
            buffer.append(ch, start, length);
        }
    }
```

**DatabaseHelper:**

```
    // add to StoreDetails table
    public void addtoStoreDetail(StoreDetails storeDetails) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = null;
        InsertHelper ih = null;
        try {
            database = getWritableDatabase();
            ih = new InsertHelper(database, "StoreDetails");

            // Get the numeric indexes for each of the columns that we're updating
            final int idColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("_id");
            final int nameColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("StoreName");
            ...
            final int descColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("StoreDescription");

            // Add the data for each column
            ih.bind(idColumn, storeDetails.getStoreId());
            ih.bind(nameColumn, storeDetails.getStoreName());
            ...
            ih.bind(descColumn, storeDetails.getStoreDescription());

            // Insert the row into the database.
            ih.execute();
        } finally {
            ih.close();
            safeCloseDataBase(database);
        }
    }
```

The loaded xml document is 6000+ lines long. When testing on the device it stops inserting after around halfway (no errors) which takes about 4-5 minutes.  On the emulator however, it runs rather quickly, writing all lines to the database in about 20 seconds.  I have log statements that run when the db is opened, data added, then closed.  The LogCat outputs are significantly slower when running on the device.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Why is my data taking so long to write?  I thought the improved InsertHelper would help, but unfortunately not even a little faster.  Can someone point out my flaw(s) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also counted on `InsertHelper` improving singificantly the speed, but the difference wasnt that drastic when I tested it.

Still the strength of the `InsertHelper` is in multiple inserts, because it compiles the query just once. The way you do it you declare new `InsertHelper` for every insert, which is bypassing the one-time-compilation improvement. Try using the same instance for multiple inserts.

However, I do not think that 6000+ inserts will go in less than a minute on slow device.

**EDIT** Also make sure you fetch the column indices only once, this will speed up a bit more. Place these outside the loop for the batch insert.

```
 // Get the numeric indexes for each of the columns that we're updating
 final int idColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("_id");
 final int nameColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("StoreName");
 final int descColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("StoreDescription");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Ok so I changed this: dBHelper.addtoStoreDetail(storeDetails); to this: arrayList.add(StoreDetails);  When I loop over the list to initiate the InsertHelper dance, my arrayList only contains the last row... why is "add" only adding the last row?  Once this is sorted, I should be back on track.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing a batch insert like this, You might do better to set up a special action in your DB helper for it.  Right now, you are opening and closing the connection to the SQLite DB every time you insert a row, which is going to slow you down significantly. For the batch process, set it up so that you can maintain the connection for the whole import Job.  I think the reason that it is faster in the emulator is that, while running, the emulator exists entirely in memory - so although it intentionally slows down your CPU speed, File IO comes a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to connecting the database just once could the database connection be set not to commit the changes after each insert but only once at the end of the batch? I tried to browse Android dev docs but couldn't find an exact instructions how to do this (or is it already set so). On other platforms setting SQLite driver's AutoCommit to false and committing only at the end of the batch can improve insert speeds significantly.